# How to print only values from findAll() object of jpa repository in java

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa

It's a Rest api, I am using Jpa repository findAll() to extract all values in the db.

Actually I am getting json response as

```
{ 

   {"Currency" : "Rupee"},

   {"Currency" : "Dollar"},

   {"Currency" : "Euro"},

   {"Currency" : "Pound"}

}
```

But I need

```
{["Rupee","Dollar","Euro","Pound"]}
```

### [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLHsx.png) Controller code

[Service Impl code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGKGH.png)
[JPA Repository code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuVrg.png)

[4] Entity layer CURRIENCIES_TABLE.java

Comment: Can you share your code please!

Comment: posted. click on 1 you can find end point.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended create a mapper, in the mapper you could create a function that convert the actual object that you return to other object that adapt to your necessities. The return object must be a object that contains a list of string.

Comment: Mapper is a good choice, I agree.
Also, you can stream your object list get your currency values and then to this currency value stream to list again. For example;

myList.stream().map(Currency::getValue).toList()